# How to redirect redirect mock requests in Spring MVC REST test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, integration-testing

In my web.xml I mapped the servlet to /api like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>todo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>todo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

So for the controller using `@RequestMapping(value = "/todo", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, it actually gets mapped to "/api/todo"

But in test when I call `mockMvc.perform(get("/api/todo/"))` I got a 404. I have to call `get("/todo/")` to get the correct mapping in test. I hope to map the  controller in test like in actual scenario. Is that possible?

I'm using `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` in test and I tried

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/api/**").addResourceLocations("/");
}
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will notice when you setup your `MockMvc` configuration that you don't specify the location of a deployment descriptor, your web.xml. That is because `MockMvc` doesn't test your configuration of a `DispatcherServlet`. It tests your MVC configuration, `@Controller` beans and the like.

If you look at the source, `MockMvc` creates a `TestDispatcherServlet` which loads and uses your web application context.

In other words, the servlet `url-pattern` path is irrelevant to `MockMvc`. You make your requests as if there was no such path.

You state

> I hope to map the controller in test like in actual scenario.

you will need to use a different test strategy. Fully deploy your web application and use an HTTP client to make requests and validate what you get back.

You've tagged `unit-testing`. Testing in a full environment is not unit testing, it is integration and system testing.

---

Note that this

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/api/**").addResourceLocations("/");
}
```

has nothing to do with the above. Its purpose is to serve static resources from some path in your webapp. It has nothing to do with your servlet's `url-pattern` or the path to your controllers.