# How are absolute paths applied when combining @RequestMapping, @RestController, and web.xml, and why does my test fail?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

We have a servlet defined in our `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In our controller class, we use both `@RequestMapping` and `@RestController`.

```
package com.example.foo;

@RestController("/foo/bar/v1")
public class Baz {
  @RequestMapping(value="/bar/v1/abc" /* ... */)
  public String doXyz() {
```

Now, I know the [Spring documentation for RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path--) says

> When used at the type level, all method-level mappings inherit this
>   primary mapping, narrowing it for a specific handler method.

In other words, when I define a `@RequestMapping("/foo")` on class level, anything I define on the method level would be ***appended***. For the example above, if the path was defined in a `@RequestMapping("/foo/bar/v1")` on class level, instead of in the `@RestController`, I would thus expect `/foo/bar/v1/bar/v1/abc` - or `/foo/bar/v1/abc` if the path on the method were relative. **Is that understanding of mine correct?**

Now, apparently, `@RestController("/foo/bar/v1")` has the same effect as `@RequestMapping("/foo/bar/v1")` in terms of request path mapping - **is that observation correct, too?**

If not, why does above code still work? Is the `/foo/` part picked up from the `web.xml`?

Now, if I leave the code as is, the following test fails:

```
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(
            get("/foo/bar/v1")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) //...
```

My guess is it fails because

1. it doesn't read the web.xml, hence doesn't know about the `/foo` prefix
2. the path in `@RequestMapping("bar/v1")` on the method level doesn't actually narrow down the one in `@restController("/foo/bar/v1")` after all.

The error message I get is

> javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.example.foo.Baz@5b800468]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter that supports this handler

This is what the context config looks like that the test loads (besides `@WebAppConfiguration`):

`<context:annotation-config/>`
`<mvc:annotation-driven/>` 
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.foo" />`

**How do the annotations and `web.xml` really work together, and what do I need to configure to make the test pass?**

Comment: `@RestController(""/foo/bar/v1")` does not do what you think it does. It doesn't do anything for the URL. With this it will create a bean and the name of the bean will be `/foo/bar/v1` it has no effect on the request mapping what so ever. Only a `@RequestMapping` on the class level would have that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, when I define a @RequestMapping("/foo") on class
>   level, anything I define on the method level would be appended. For
>   the example above, if the path was defined in a
>   @RequestMapping("/foo/bar/v1") on class level, instead of in the
>   @RestController, I would thus expect /foo/bar/v1/bar/v1/abc - or
>   /foo/bar/v1/abc if the path on the method were relative. Is that
>   understanding of mine correct?

If you define `@RequestMapping(value="/foo/bar/v1")` at class level and `@RequestMapping(value="/bar/v1/abc")` at method level , then, your complete url will become as `/foo/bar/v1/bar/v1/abc` i.e., both the request mapping strings will be appended simply (i.e., it will not work like `/foo/bar/v1/abc`)

> @RestController("/foo/bar/v1") has the same effect as
>   @RequestMapping("/foo/bar/v1") in terms of request path mapping - is
>   that observation correct, too?

No, it is not the same effect, because when you add `@RestController("/foo/bar/v1")` at the class level, this has nothing to do with the request url mapping, rather here, **you are simply naming your controller bean as `/foo/bar/v1`**, this has no effect on request mapping url.

> How do the annotations and web.xml really work together, and what do I
>   need to configure to make the test pass?

`servlet-mapping` in web.xml only acts as the global url to the `DispatcherServlet` (Front Controller) and then the DispatcherServlet will delegate the request to the respective Controller methods by evaluating the url against the `RequestMapping`.

In order to make the test pass with the url `/foo/bar/v1`, you can map the controller as below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/foo/")
public class Baz {

  @RequestMapping(value="bar/v1", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String doXyz() { 

  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but funnily enough, my example above seems to be working happily on live (even though it doesn't pass my new test)... And the test passes if I just specify the path as `@RestController("/foo/bar/v1")`, without mentioning the path in any `@RequestMapping` annotation (neither on method nor on class level) - although I haven't tried to deploy that yet. Your answer is pretty much what I expected (save I wasn't sure if there was a difference between absolute and relative paths in the method level `@RequestMapping`), but it doesn't seem to agree with what I am observing... :(

Comment: How did you check the 'live' version? Did you decompile the actual .class and check? Surely, there is a gap, I don't think `@RestController("/foo/bar/v1")`  maps the controller to any url, rather it just names the controller as explained above.

Comment: Admittedly, I only looked at trunk, not tag, but in trunk the code pretty much looks like the example. I joined a new project, and decided to write a test for the existing code before I introduce my change - only I have issues puzzling together what is actually going on, as you can see from my previous comment and the question... :) And the code from tag is deployed. But no, I didn't decompile. Neither did I actually use a REST client to verify there is no bug. Maybe I should.

Comment: You need to decompile and check

Comment: The decompiled version looks exactly as the example above, when it comes to annotations... But I've seen elsewhere that [MockMvc doesn't read out the `web.xml` file (i.e. deployment descriptor)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20010156/2018047). Apparently, there are [ways](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25390866/2018047) [to make it work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28194383/2018047) - and knowing the [different parts of the path](https://coderanch.com/t/169141/#818977) helps... ;) I will have to double-check if `@RestController('path')` on its own really does work, though, or if something was cached…